# C# web api parse URL to only get the method method name up till the /

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I have some web api urls that I'm restricting people to with both a token and a list of api addresses

Previously I was looking for  their token and that it matches up with a valid api address such as

```
api/request
```

The code I wrote for that is

```
string prefixSearched = "api";
string parsedUrl =  consumer.ApiAddressRequested.Substring(
                        consumer.ApiAddressRequested.IndexOf(prefixSearched, StringComparison.Ordinal) +
                        prefixSearched.Length);
string finalSearch = prefixSearched + parsedUrl;
```

So above worked for me when URL is `http://localhost:29001/api/request`

However I am realizing that myself and others have api services that end up looking like this

```
`http://localhost:29001/GetQAByDateTime/date/2-15-2017/time/11`
```

So other than locking down the main FQDM ,  I'm thinking that i really only want to enter  `GetQAByDateTime` into the database , so how can I just parse that out of the url string?

Seems like I need to be able to parse out things like `api/request` and then also these ones without `api/`

I think that most with be  `api/something` but then the anomalies of `GetSomething`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UriTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the url:

```
var host = new Uri("http://localhost:29001");
var apiTemplate = new UriTemplate("{api}/{*params}", true);

var match = apiTemplate.Match(host, new Uri("http://localhost:29001/GetQAByDateTime/date/2-15-2017/time/11"));
if (match == null)
    throw new ArgumentException();

Console.WriteLine(match.BoundVariables["api"]);     // GetQAByDateTime
Console.WriteLine(match.BoundVariables["params"]);  // date/2-15-2017/time/11
```

What you can expect:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
|                              Url                              |       API        |         Params          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| http://localhost:29001/GetSomething                           | GetSomething     |                         |
| http://localhost:29001/GetSomething2/                         | GetSomething2    |                         |
| http://localhost:29001/GetQAByDateTime/date/2-15-2017/time/11 | GetQAByDateTime  | date/2-15-2017/time/11  |
| http://localhost:29001/GetQAByDateTime/dat11                  | GetQAByDateTime  | dat11                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Hey ,  so if i publish to a server then and say i left top line there, but then in new Uri("   I used httpcontext....  etc... )    then essentially this would not be a match and it would break,  right?   `var match = apiTemplate.Match(host,etc`

Comment: I creating a new question btw   thanks    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689379/c-sharp-net-uritemplate-match-url-from-a-whitelist-or-pool-or-servers