# C# .net UriTemplate match url from a whitelist or pool or servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

You can use UriTemplate to parse the url:

I have this code in which locally on `localhost:29001`  I set the host to be a specific `Uri` and then I check to if it is a `Match`

In my real code I do have the the line

```
var absoluteUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

of which is used like this

```
var match = apiTemplate.Match(host, new Uri(absoluteUri));
```

but essentially this is what the code is going to look like in C# from it running.

```
var host = new Uri("http://localhost:29001");
var apiTemplate = new UriTemplate("{api}/{*params}", true);

var match = apiTemplate.Match(host, new Uri("http://localhost:29001/GetQAByDateTime/date/2-15-2017/time/11"));
if (match == null)
    throw new ArgumentException();

Console.WriteLine(match.BoundVariables["api"]);     // GetQAByDateTime
Console.WriteLine(match.BoundVariables["params"]);  // date/2-15-2017/time/11
```

So Essentially I do not want to `hardcode` the  `host`

```
  var host = new Uri("http://localhost:29001");
```

Sure, i can get the server name from the `HttpContext` but what is the point?  Shouldn't I want to check for a pool or servers  like

```
localhost
localhost:290001
https://myserver.com
https://myStagingServer/website
etc..
```

How can I match on a pool of these?

Comment: So I was using linqpad and i see that `var match` is the `UriTemplateMatch` and I can see how it is a complex object that is useful.   However I can change `var host = new Uri("http://blahblahliterally")`  and i still get the same results  so I don't understand what `.Match` is really doing

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the host directly from`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`:

```
var uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
var host = new Uri(uri.Scheme + "://" + x.Authority);
```

EDIT: I should add that `Uri.Host` is avoided because "Unlike the Authority property, this property value does not include the port number."

Comment: wait, what is   x.Authority ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller The [`Authority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority(v=vs.110).aspx) property is typically a server DNS host name or IP address. This property might include the service port number if it differs from the default port for the URI. If the Authority component contains reserved characters, these are escaped in the string value returned by this property.